# Assign a value to an attribute name

Tags: ruby, attributes, assign

I want to initialize `attr3='c'`, the number of attribute can change.

```
class MyClass
    attr_accessor :attr1, :attr2, :attr3
    def initialize(attr1 = 1, attr2 = 2, attr3 = 3)
         @attr1 = attr1
         @attr2 = attr2
         @attr3 = attr3
    end
end

myclass = MyClass.new
myclass.attr1 # => 1
myclass.attr2 # => 2
myclass.attr3 # => 3

myclass = MyClass.new('c')
myclass.attr1 # => c
myclass.attr2 # => 2
myclass.attr3 # => 3
```

I tried to assign a value to an attribute name.

```
myclass = MyClass.new({attr3 : 'c'}) # => but that doesn't work
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to assign a value to an attribute name?
Thank you to @Uri Agassi and @DaveMongoose!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write your initializer to take a hash:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  # If the attributes hash doesn't have the relevant key, set it to default:
  @attr1 = attributes.fetch(:attr1, 1)
  @attr2 = attributes.fetch(:attr2, 2)
  @attr3 = attributes.fetch(:attr3, 3)
end
```

For a more generic solution, you can loop through the keys in the hash:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  attributes.each do |key, value|
    send("#{key}=", value) if respond_to?("#{key}=")
  end
end
```

Comment: Hash#fetch accepts a default without the need for logical or operators. There's no need to call `to_s` inside string interpolation, and the underscore nomenclature is typically reserved to indicate a private instance variable or method, not a method argument (except when used alone, in which case it's for discarding params).

Answer (score 1):

To have named defaults you should use (provided that you use [Ruby 2.0 and up](http://brainspec.com/blog/2012/10/08/keyword-arguments-ruby-2-0/)):

```
def initialize(attr1: 1, attr2: 2, attr3: 3)
     @attr1 = attr1
     @attr2 = attr2
     @attr3 = attr3
end
```

mind you that this method will *not* work in conjunction with the previous method:

```
myclass = MyClass.new
myclass.attr1 # => 1
myclass.attr2 # => 2
myclass.attr3 # => 3

myclass = MyClass.new(attr1: 'c')
myclass.attr1 # => c
myclass.attr2 # => 2
myclass.attr3 # => 3

myclass = MyClass.new('c') # ERROR!
```

Comment: please add the required ruby version :)

Comment: Just an information for novices like me : (attr1: 1) => OK // (attr1 : 1) => ERROR